# efficient way of updating tables using mysql c api

Tags: mysql, c

I 'm doing an data logger project where  i get data from the sensors and store them in a database . I'm using mysql database which is hosted on Beaglebone (Arm linux based computer ),i'm using C api's to work with the mysql database.

I poll the sensors with a sample time of 5 seconds and get data from them and store them onto the tables as per the below code , the code does what is meant to do i just wanted to know whether there's an efficient way of updating the  tables .Below is the code

```
    #include <my_global.h>
    #include <mysql.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {

    /* creates a new mysql object */
     MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

     float tempval = 0;
     float humidval=0;

     char query[100]={0};

     if (con == NULL) 
     {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
          exit(1);
     }

    /* connect to db */
     if(mysql_real_connect(con,"localhost","root","passwrd12#",0,0,0,0)==NULL)
     {
         fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
         mysql_close(con);
         exit(1);

     }
/* Select the db */

      if(mysql_select_db(con,"TestDb")!=0)
      {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s \n",mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
      }

     while(1)
     {

      //Read temperature and humidity sensors on pin1 and pin2 

        tempval=Read_Sensordata(1);
        humidval=Read_Sensordata(2)

      memset(query,0,sizeof query);

/* update the temperature and humidity values */    
      sprintf(query,"UPDATE Datavalues SET Temperature = %f,Humidity = %f,Time=NOW() WHERE Rownum=0",tempval,humidval);

      if (mysql_query(con,query)) 
      {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
          mysql_close(con);
          exit(1);
      }

       usleep(5000000);


     }
      mysql_close(con);

      exit(0);

    }
```

Comment: Define "efficient". What is wrong with your code? Did you mean to post this on CodeReview?

Comment: The thing is done , thanks.

Comment: Yes, I know. That does not matter. Stack Overflow is not for _you_. That you got _your_ problem solved is entirely irrelevant. Your question is supposed to help somebody else some day, so please fix it by addressing my previous comment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : I follwed the answer given below and will modify my code . was using the above code these days . And from now on i'll ensure that similar kind of questions will be posted in code review and not here . I didnt know that there was a site on code reviews on stack exchange .Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than execute a fresh query each time, you could [prepare](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html) the query once and execute it each time with the revised values.  For example (without any error checking):

```c
strmov(query, "               \
  UPDATE Datavalues           \
  SET    Temperature = ?,     \
         Humidity    = ?,     \
         Time        = NOW()  \
  WHERE  Rownum      = 0      \
");

MYSQL_STMT *stmt = mysql_stmt_init(con);
mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, query, strlen(query));

MYSQL_BIND bind[2];
memset(bind, 0, sizeof(bind));
bind[0].buffer_type = bind[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_FLOAT;
bind[0].buffer = (char *) &tempval;
bind[1].buffer = (char *) &humidval;
mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, bind);

while (1) {
  tempval  = Read_Sensordata(1);
  humidval = Read_Sensordata(2);
  mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);
  usleep(5000000);
}

mysql_stmt_close(stmt);
```

Furthermore, you may wish to consider utilising MySQL's [Automatic Initialization and Updating for `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html) to save you having to explicitly set the `Time` column from within the `UPDATE` command.